# Children's book where a mouse/rat takes a bite out of a book

Tags: identification-request

During my years as an elementary librarian, I read a book to some kindergarteners. A student who remembers me reading it to his class returned and wanted to read it again.

He said he thinks the character was a mouse or rat, at one point takes a bite out of the book. I can only imagine it may have been one I read regarding book care. The year would have been around 2007-2010.

Comment: So the rodent took a bite out of the actual book that they were in, maybe leading to some cutout or marking on the book where they "ate" it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please also add the language of the book?

Comment: Probably not your book, but https://www.momfessionals.com/2018/04/books-lately.html mentions *The Incredible Book Eating Boy* which features the last page and back cover having a bite taken out of them.

Answer (score 1):

Monique Felix has a series of books without words about a mouse. I'm fairly sure that in [The House](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/231872.The_House), the mouse takes bites out of the book, but I also remember it happening in  some of the other books in the series. Could it have been one of these?

On the other hand, I don't think you could have “read” these books to your classs, because as I remember, they don't have any words in them, just pictures.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I definitely read it aloud. I appreciate your thoughts and I'll take a look at the series anyway.